# After git remote remove, my local commit status changed

Tags: git

I just did `git remote remove origin` and re-add the same remote origin again. However, only after that did I realized that I got myself into a situation that I don't know how to recover, because before doing `git remote remove origin`, I had:

```
$ git status 
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

But now:

```
$ git status 
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

What should I do now? How can I make `git` know that my branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits? Thx.

Comment: Try `git fetch origin`.

Answer (score 3):

Just set your upstream branch to point to your new `origin`:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master
```

Comment: Thx! but I got `error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/master' does not exist`. Doing `git fetch` fixed it. Please update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It just removed your connection with git. You don't need to worry anything because this is just connection lost. You can do clone again, which is easy solution.

**I am providing exact solution that I checked below to solve your issue.**

When you do `git remote remove origin`, the `config` file inside `.git` directory looks something like this.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
```

When you again make git connection using

```
  git remote add origin userName@https://github.com/userName/repoName
```

it again creates git connection and now, your `.git` folder's `config` looks like below

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
[remote "origin"]
    url = userName@https://github.com/userName/repoName
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Now, you add `upstream` by

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/userName/repoName
```

Do `git remote -v`to list `upstream, origin, master` etc.

Now, you can `pull` (or `fetch` and `merge`) from `master`. I am doing direct `pull` here. `git pull https://github.com/userName/repoName`

Now, everything works. I checked everything.